# converting back custom object from object type and improving code

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a peice of code where i pack several type of object in an collection of object type. They need to be inserted in a database.
I use EF core 2.1 and a popular extention know as EFCore.BulkExtensions 
below the code:

```
 List<object> mappedContent = MapContent(elements, mappings);// a million records

List<typeA> tAlist= new List<typeA>();
List<typeB> tBlist= new List<typeB>();
List<typeC> tClist= new List<typeC>();


            foreach (var record in mappedContent)
            {
                switch (record.GetType().Name)
                {
                    case "TypeA":
                        tAlist.Add((TypeA)record);
                        break;
                    case "typeB":
                        tBlist.Add((typeB)record);
                        break;
                    case "typeC":
                        tClist.Add((typeC)record);
                        break;
                   default:
                    Throw new Exception(" Unknown type");

}
}

 context.BulkInsert(tAlist);
 context.BulkInsert(tBlist);
 context.BulkInsert(tClist );
```

I have more than 20 different objects type and i'm wondering if i can avoid some repetition in the code. Also, i want to do this without affecting performance or even improve the current performance which is quite  acceptable thanks to the library that i'm using.

Many thanks in advance

B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

```
var tAlist = mappedContent.OfType<TypeA>();
// do wonderful fun stuff with a list of TypeA
```

Note, performance wise this will probably be better than what you were using. However the source to `OfType` is basically:

```
foreach (object obj in source) 
{
    if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;
}
```

Its basically time complexity O(n) for every time you call it.

If you want a more efficient approach yet more verbose, similar to what you have, yet more modern and performant approach. You could use C# 7.0 *Pattern Matching* in a `switch`:

```
foreach (var record in mappedContent)
    switch (record )
    {
        case TypeA typeA:
            tAlist.Add(typeA);
            break;
        ...
```

It will give you flat O(n), though you will have to make 20 lists etc.

Comment: Yes, the performance got improved because you use switch case on string type but OfType extension method check the type of each item using "is" keyword.